# Is this the right way to do dependency injection in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to inject dependencies into my Django view (controller?). Here's some background.

Normally, the `urls.py` file is what handles the routing. It is usually something like this:

```
 urlpatterns = [
     path("", views.get_all_posts, name="get_all_posts"),
     path("<int:post_id>", views.get_post, name="get_post"),
     path("create", views.create_post, name="create_post"),
 ]
```

The problem with this, is that once you get to `create_post` for instance, you might have a dependency on a service that creates posts:

```
# views.py
...

def create_post(self):
    svc = PostCreationService()
    svc.create_post()
```

This kind of pattern is difficult to test. While I know python testing libraries have tools to mock this sort of thing, I'd rather inject the dependency into the view. Here's what I came up with.

A Controller class that has a static method, `export(deps)` that takes in a list of dependencies and returns a list of url pattern objects:

```
class ApiController(object):

    @staticmethod
    def export(**deps):
        ctrl = ApiController(**deps)
        return [
            path("", ctrl.get_all_posts, name="get_all_posts"),
            path("<int:post_id>", ctrl.get_post, name="get_post"),
            path("create", ctrl.create_post, name="create_post"),
        ]

    def __init__(self, **deps):
        self.deps = deps

    def get_all_posts():
        pass
    ...
```

This looks janky, but I'm not aware of any other way to do what I'm trying to do. The controller needs to return a list of url patterns, and it also needs to take in a list of dependencies. Using the above technique, I can do this in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = ApiController.export(foo_service=(lambda x: x))
```

I am now free to use `foo_service` in any of the methods of `ApiController`.

**Note:**

One alternative would be for the constructor to return the list of urls, but I don't see that as a huge improvement over this. In fact, it strikes me as being more confusing because the class constructor would return a list instead of an instance of the class.

**Note 2:**

I'm aware that python has mocking tools for mocking class members. Please don't suggest using them. I'd like to use DI as the way to control and manage dependencies.

Any ideas on what the best way to do this is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider injecting using decorators:

```
from functools import wraps

class ServiceInjector:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deps = {}

    def register(self, name=None):

        name = name
        def decorator(thing):
            """
            thing here can be class or function or anything really
            """

            if not name:
                if not hasattr(thing, "__name__"):
                    raise Exception("no name")
                thing_name = thing.__name__
            else:
                thing_name = name
            self.deps[thing_name] = thing
            return thing

        return decorator

    def inject(self, func):

        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            new_args = args + (self.deps, )
            return func(*new_args, **kwargs)

        return decorated

# usage:


si = ServiceInjector()

# use func.__name__, registering func
@si.register()
def foo(*args):
    return sum(args)


# we can rename what it's been registered as, here, the class is registered 
# with name `UpperCase` instead of the class name `UpperCaseRepresentation`
@si.register(name="UpperCase")
class UpperCaseRepresentation:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value.upper()

#register float
si.register(name="PI")(3.141592653)


# inject into functions
@si.inject 
def bar(a, b, c, _deps): # the last one in *args would be receiving the dependencies
    UpperCase, PI, foo = _deps['UpperCase'], _deps['PI'], _deps['foo']
    print(UpperCase('abc')) # ABC
    print(PI) # 3.141592653
    print(foo(a, b, c, 4, 5)) # = 15

bar(1, 2, 3)

# inject into class methods
class Foo:

    @si.inject
    def my_method(self, a, b, _deps, kwarg1=30):
        return _deps['foo'](a, b, kwarg1)

print(Foo().my_method(1, 2, kwarg1=50)) # = 53
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont follow what's going on here. Can you explain? Why is `UpperCase` registered to `MyClass` but neither class uses the other?

Comment: Sorry, the naming was bad, I have changed them. I was just trying to show that you can name the thing you want to register, if name is not supplied, it would use the `__name__` of the object to register it. The last example was only there to show that the `@si.inject`  decorator works with class methods too.

Comment: I like this idea. However, the only issue I see here is that you would get always the whole dictionary of dependencies, probably not necessary where the @inject decorator is being used. But if the same implementation allowed for specifying what dependencies I want to inject, like in React Native, that would be even better. E.g.: `@inject('db', 'mailer') def my_func(*args, **kwargs):` where kwargs would contain the desired dependencies.

Comment: I initially did that, but then it might clash with existing kwargs in function. limiting what goes into the injection would require creating a new dictionary with keys filtered out, for this "last args" approach, it just doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 14):

You could take a look at https://github.com/ets-labs/python-dependency-injector, but that is a pretty big setup.

You could also create something small like a Service factory

```py
# services.py
class ServiceFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__services = {}

    def register(self, name, service_class):
        # Maybe add some validation
        self.__services[name] = service_class

    def create(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        # Maybe add some error handling or fallbacks
        return self.__services[name](*args, **kwargs)

factory = ServiceFactory()


# In your settings.py for example
from services import factory
factory.register('post_creation', PostCreationService)


# Or maybe in apps.ready do auto_load that will loop all apps and get config from services.py


# In your views.py
from services import factory

def create_post(self):
    svc = factory.create('post_creation')
    svc.create_post()


# In your tests.py
from services import factory

def setUp(self):
    factory.register('post_creation', FakePostCreationService)
```

Answer (score 6):

While reading `Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns` and trying to apply the examples to a django app I came up with the following:

```py
# views.py

class IndexView(View):
    # Must include this to bypass django's validation
    product_service: IProductService = None
    
    # Init method not necessary but more explicit
    def __init__(self, product_service: IProductService):
        self.product_service = product_service

    def get(self, request):
        self.product_service.do_stuff()
        ...

# urls.py

# Construct dependencies. I guess this is the closest to the entry-point we can get
# with Django.
repo = DjangoProductRepository()
product_service = ProductService(repo)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", 
         IndexView.as_view(product_service=product_service),
         name="index"),
]
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29821870)

Comment: This method of injection via the constructor is by far the best method IMO. It's explicitly clear what's going on and allows for type checking the injected implementation.

Comment: As far as I understand, this method of injection doesn't allow injecting mocks during testing. The only way to test this code is to use monkey patching again. Or constructing views manually in the unit testing code.

Comment: Yes this assumes the view will be initialized with the dependencies in the unit test itself, and called manually using a RequestFactory for example

Answer (score 3):

This is only an updated version of [rabbit.aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3452345/rabbit-aaron) reply above. My idea is to be able to specify which dependencies to inject instead of getting a dictionary with all registered dependencies.

```
from functools import wraps

class ServiceInjector:
    deps = {}

    def register(self, name=None):
        name = name

        def decorator(thing):
            """
            thing here can be class or function or anything really
            """

            if not name:
                if not hasattr(thing, '__name__'):
                    raise Exception('no name')
                thing_name = thing.__name__
            else:
                thing_name = name
            self.__class__.deps[thing_name] = thing
            return thing

        return decorator

    class inject:
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self.selected_deps = args

        def __call__(self, func):
            @wraps(func)
            def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
                selected_deps = {k: v for k, v in ServiceInjector.deps.items() if k in self.selected_deps}
                new_kwargs = {**kwargs, **selected_deps}
                return func(*args, **new_kwargs)

            return decorated
```

## Usage:

```
si = ServiceInjector()

# use func.__name__, registering func
@si.register()
def foo(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

### Custom naming still works

```
@si.register(name='uppercase')
class UpperCaseRepresentation:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value.upper()
```

### Register float

```
si.register(name="PI")(3.141592653)
```

### Inject into functions

```
@si.inject('foo', 'PI', 'uppercase')
def bar(a, b, c, uppercase: UpperCaseRepresentation, **kwargs):
    """
    You can specify dependencies as keyword arguments and add typehint annotation.
    """
    UpperCase, foo = kwargs['UpperCase'], kwargs['foo']
    print(uppercase('abc')) # ABC
    print(PI) # 3.141592653
    print(foo(a, b, c, 4, 5)) # = 15

bar(1, 2, 3)
```

### Inject into class methods

```
class Bar:
    @si.inject('foo')
    def my_method(self, a, b, foo, kwarg1=30):
        return foo(a, b, kwarg1)

print(Bar().my_method(1, 2, kwarg1=50)) # = 53
```

Comment: The last one where you show in the "inject into class method" might not work if you're injecting more than one item, for cpython under version 3.6. as the dictionary isn't ordered.

Comment: Dependencies are registered, injected, and used as dictionary keys. I don't think non-ordered dicts will be a problem. Just tested the last case with two dependencies `@inject('foo', 'uppercase')` and then defining the method `def my_method(self, a, b, uppercase, foo, kwarg1=30)` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the flask route and export a class instance with a property that initializes and caches the service on first access. E.g:

```py
def default_factory():
    pass

# service.py
class ServiceProvider:
    def __init__(self, create_instance=default_factory):
        self.create_instance = create_instance

    _instance = None

    @property
    def service(self):
       if self._instance:
           return self._instance
       self._instance = self.create_instance()
       return self._instance

service_provider = ServiceProvider()
```

```py
from .service import service_provider

# views.py
def view(request):
    service_provider.service.do_stuff()
    # etc.
```

This has the advantages of being easy to mock and not having any magic.

Answer (score 0):

The most boring solution I could come up with involves using class variables:

```py
# Module services.post_service
def default_create_post():
    return "foo"

class Provider:
    create_post = default_create_post
```

Then you could import and use normally in a view or elsewhere:

```py
from services import post_service

post_service.Provider.create_post()
# Should return "foo"
```

And when testing it could be swapped out before being called:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from services import post_service
from unittest.mock import patch

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @patch('services.post_service.default_create_post')
    def test_some_view(self, mock_create_post):
        mock_create_post.return_value = "bar"
        post_service.Provider.create_post = mock_create_post
        # Now when calling post_service.Provider.create_post it should just return "bar"
```